# Tag Synonym Request [playstation-3] -> [ps3]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There are quite a few questions tagged [playstation-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-3), but a lot more with [ps3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps3).

Obviously, there is a tag that is redundant here, so one of the should be merged with the other one.